# Run Python Selenium webdriver in ssh

Tags: python, selenium, ssh

I want to run selenium webdriver in a remote server. I just tried a really simple script:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800,600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print browser.title
browser.quit()
display.stop()
```

The error is:

```
File "1.py", line 7, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
File "/home/shunyang/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/home/shunyang/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 85, in start
self.assert_process_still_running()
File "/home/shunyang/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in assert_process_still_running
% (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:
Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. 
Status code was: 1
```

I wonder what is wrong with my setup and how to solve this issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After trying many things, updating chrome solved it :)

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Check your version with `google-chrome --version` and download the chromedriver for the version you have.

Comment: If I run the script from the terminal (connected to Ubuntu via VNC Viewer), it works. But if I run the script via PuTTy (SSH connection from Windows), it fails (Chrome doesn't start correctly).

Comment: What are your chromedriver configurations? Have you set headless?
`chrome_options = Options()`
`chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")`
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)`

Answer (score 0):

If you change Chrome for Firefox, it works just fine (as long as you have correct version of Firefox - selenium always catches up, but it has some delay - so older version might be needed (update selenium and check what version works with it).

As for Chrome, try giving it path in argument. For example: `driver = webdriver.Chrome('PATH\TO\CHROME')`.