# How to run selenium webdriver on cloud server with ssh access

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run selenium on my remote server using headless mode but i am not getting any success

```py
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
>>> options = Options()
>>> options.headless = True
>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Output:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: 
Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running,
 so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Stacktrace:
#0 0x55fd03b17fb3 <unknown>
#1 0x55fd037eb4a7 <unknown>
#2 0x55fd0381ec93 <unknown>
#3 0x55fd0381b10c <unknown>
#4 0x55fd0385dac6 <unknown>
#5 0x55fd03854713 <unknown>
#6 0x55fd0382718b <unknown>
#7 0x55fd03827f7e <unknown>
#8 0x55fd03add8d8 <unknown>
#9 0x55fd03ae1800 <unknown>
#10 0x55fd03aebcfc <unknown>
#11 0x55fd03ae2418 <unknown>
#12 0x55fd03aaf42f <unknown>
#13 0x55fd03b064e8 <unknown>
#14 0x55fd03b066b4 <unknown>
#15 0x55fd03b17143 <unknown>
#16 0x7f142b4ffac3 <unknown>
```

I also tried to use [pyvirtualdisplay](https://pypi.org/project/PyVirtualDisplay/) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799134/run-python-selenium-webdriver-in-ssh) answer but it also outputs the same error

selenium version - `4.14.0` | chrome version - `Google Chrome 118.0.5993.117`

Answer (score -1):

i was trying to execute the script as root that's why i was facing these errors following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71699916/22309631) suggested me to use no sandbox argument to open my browser and it fixed the error also I was using depreciated property for headless which i needed to fix. This is the code which will work for anyone else who is searching for it

```py
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
>>> options = Options()
>>> options.add_argument("--headless")
>>> options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") # No need if running without su
>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```